# How to remove dictionary from a list if all values of keys are null

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

Output:

```
{
        "id": 243,
        "name": "DC KD Postpaid",
        "display_name": "DC KD Postpaid disp.",
        "asigned": [
            {
                "id": null,
                "user": null,
                "email": null,
                "phone": null,
                "fullname": null
            },
            {
                "id": 526,
                "user": "Suraj6",
                "email": "dckd@gmail.com",
                "phone": "9865325285",
                "fullname": "Suraj"
            }
        ]
    }
```

CentresAssigned Serializer

```
class CentresAssigned(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    asigned = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

class Meta:
    model = Centers
    fields = ["id", "name", "display_name", "asigned"]

def get_asigned(self, obj):
    if obj.asigned:
        return PanelUserSerializerCopy(obj.asigned, many=True).data
    else:
        return None
```

PanelUserSerializerCopy

```
class PanelUserSerializerCopy(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    email = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    phone = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    fullname = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

class Meta:
    model = panel_models.PanelUser
    fields = (
        "id",
        "user",
        "email",
        "phone",
        "fullname"
    )

def get_id(self, obj):
    if obj.user and obj.user.usergroup == 'CCPartner':
        return obj.id
    else:
        return None

def get_user(self, obj):
    if obj.user and obj.user.usergroup == 'CCPartner':
        return obj.user.username
    else:
        return None

def get_email(self, obj):
    if obj.user and obj.user.usergroup == 'CCPartner':
        return obj.user.email
    else:
        return None

def get_phone(self, obj):
    if obj.user and obj.user.usergroup == 'CCPartner':
        return obj.user.phonenumber
    else:
        return None

def get_fullname(self, obj):
    return obj.user.fullname if obj.user and obj.user.usergroup == 'CCPartner' else None
```

As in the output the first dictionary of all keys contains null value. So i do not want this in the list. How to do this. I am learning Python and DRF and I searched and found items() and del() method but how to apply here. I am having difficulty. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you !!

Comment: Is the json something you are receiving from an external api or something you can control? Not to deflect from your original question, but ideally this would be handled on the sender's side rather than the receivers

Comment: Hi @joshmeranda I can control. I am coding it. Dictionary inside list returning null if usergroup is not CCPartenr.

Comment: What about cases where only some values are null? Should they also be filtered, or is it only in the case where *all* values are null?

Comment: Null is only coming inside any dictionary if usergroup is not CCPartner so if usergroup is not CCPartner all values will always be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to assign the original list to a filtered list:

```py
some_list = [{'a': None, 'b': None}, {'a': 0, 'b': 0}]

filtered_list = filter(lambda d: all(True if i is not None else False for i in d.values()),
                       some_list)
```

You could also iterate over each dictionary by index and delete the bad values:

```py
for i in range(len(some_list)):
    if all(True if v is not None else False for v in some_list[i].values()):
        del(some_list[i])
```

Note that in my `all` checks I am checking if the value is explicitly `None`. Otherwise you may end up with not-none but Falsey values like `""` or `[]` triggering a filter or delete. If that is not a concern you could simplify the samples I gave even more.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter a dictionary based on if *all* its values are null:

```py
if all(d.values()):
    # keep d
# otherwise throw out
```

If you want to filter a dictionary based on if *any* of its values are null:

```py
if any(d.values()):
    # keep d
# otherwise throw out
```

Also, if you are working with `JSON` you may want to consider using the built-in `json` package, which converts `JSON` to Python objects (including converting Javascript's `null` to Python's `None` automatically):

```py
In [1]: import json

In [2]: s = """{"id": null, "user": null, "email": null, "phone": null, "fullname": null}"""

In [3]: json.loads(s)
Out[3]: {'id': None, 'user': None, 'email': None, 'phone': None, 'fullname': None}
```

Anyway, I loaded your JSON data into a Python dictionary called `payload` and here's an example:

```py
In [6]: [d for d in payload['asigned'] if all(d.values())]
Out[6]:
[{'id': 526,
  'user': 'Suraj6',
  'email': 'dckd@gmail.com',
  'phone': '9865325285',
  'fullname': 'Suraj'}]
```

(note that the 'asigned' key is misspelled -- should be 'assigned')

Comment: Thank you for giving time and answering.